# Bug in Implicit Waits() in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

i'm stuck in a funny situation.

Whenever I use *implicit wait* in my code, my driver is able to locate the elements via its XPath. However when I comment out the implicit wait command, then is not able to locate the element. 
Then I was doing some research, and later when I executed the code, I got a different kind of bug. It said "unknown error: cannot get automation extension".

This is really funny because, the wait commands are impacting the way the WebDriver is looking for element on the page.

Please suggest why this is happening and do share your experience if it has happened to any of you before.

The code that is throwing the error is below:-

```
package xyz;

//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Asnmnt11 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Vardhan\\workspace\\SeleniumProject\\files\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://facebook.com");
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.inputtext")).sendKeys("user@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[tabindex='2']")).sendKeys("password");
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_2']")).click();

        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove implicit wait then the driver doesn't know how long it should look for the element. It does a quick search and if the element is not present then it will throw the element not found exception.

Xpath elements take more time to find. So it is always good to have an implicit wait. Why?

1. Searching elements can take time
2. Website is still loading
3. Elements are still loading

When I ran your test without any implicit wait the driver gave up finding the element quite fast.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='u_0_2']"}

Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

This indicates that the driver was looking for the element for 0 milliseconds and it didn't find it. So it is always a good idea to have an implicit wait.

**unknown error: cannot get automation extension**

This issue is mostly an chromedriver and chrome issue. Usually is caused by using an older chromedriver version that is not compatible with your current chrome version. Chrome is automatically updated so try to update your chromedriver as well.

Comment: Correct @MArdis you are right, My thinking is just same as yours:)

Answer (score 1):

If you search element by xpath then it take more time to locate so that it is better to use Implicit or explicit wait. When I used your code without wait some time it throw `NoSuchElementException`.

AS facebook page take littile time to load and you are trying xpath to locate the elements so it is well and good to use Implicit or explicit wait.

Now as you got the issue

> unknown error: cannot get automation extension

it is chromedriver issue, sometime I also got it when i used `ChromeOptions`. So It is totally  irrelevant issue relate with Implicit wait